# How to work out degree exponent for protein-protein interaction networks (cyctoscape, NetworkAnalyzer)?

Tags: biostatistics, graph-theory

I’m working with a PPI network in cystoscape and have used NetworkAnalyzer for network parameters such as Node Degree Distribution, Shortest Path Distribution, Betweenness Centrality, etc.

When looking at the Node Degree Distribution; I can fit a line of power law and see, due to the negative slope, that my data fits the power law. However, I can’t for the life of me figure out how to work out the degree exponent.

I feel like I could be missing something very obvious. I can get the following information when fitting the power law;
Power law of the form y=ax^b , where for my network a: 89.962 b:-0.855 correlation:0.734 R-squared: 0.754

Any help or advice provided would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in a previous question with [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/565651/28500), and to summarize that reply, the calculation is:
$$\hat{\alpha} = 1 + n \left[\sum_{i=1}^n \text{ln} \frac{x_i}{x_\text{min}}\right]^{-1},$$

"where $x_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$, are the observed values of $x$ such that $x_i \le x_\text{min}$".