# Maximum likelihood estimator for power law with negative exponent

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood, estimators, power-law

### Background

I have data that roughly follows a power law with a negative exponent (up to a point; also, the parameters of the "fit" were just guesstimated by eye as a demonstration):

[image]

Now I tried using the histogram to fit a power law in the shape of

$$f(x) = k \cdot x^a,$$

but I quickly realized that this strongly depends not only on the bin size, but also on whether or not I normalize the histogram (to drop $k$ in the process). So I already inquired about how to approach this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/563731/280304), where I was (I guess unsurprisingly) told that it's not a good idea to fit a histogram at all, and to use maximum likelihood estimators (MLEs) instead.

### Question

Now I've started to read up about MLEs, and I'm starting to understand what they are all about, but mind you, I'm *not* a mathematician. First, I tried to derive the MLEs on my own, but ultimately got stuck. If

$$f(x_i; k, a) = k \cdot x_i^a,$$

then I think

$$L(x_i; k, a) = k^n \cdot \left(\prod_i^n x_i\right)^a,$$

which means

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial k} = n \cdot k^{n-1} \cdot \left(\prod_i^n x_i\right)^a, \hspace{1cm} \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = k^n \cdot \left(\prod_i^n x_i\right)^a \cdot \sum_i^n \ln{x_i}.$$

When I set them equal to zero, I can solve for $k$:

$$k = \frac{n}{\sum_i^n \ln{x_i}},$$

but that's as far as I got, and I'm not even sure if that's correct. I didn't manage to sove for $a$, but then I came across [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/66731), which is very related to my question, but unfortunately, I didn't really undestand the answers. I did look into the [referenced paper by Clauset et al.](http://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) though. But it seems that their MLEs are not concerned with my problem:

> We assume in these calculations that α > 1, since distributions with α ≤ 1 are
> not normalizable and hence cannot occur in nature. It is possible for a probability
> distribution to go as x−α with α ≤ 1 if the range of x is bounded above by some cutoff,
> but different maximum likelihood estimators are needed to fit such a distribution.

Then I found [this paper by White et al.](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/07-1288.1), which I think is concerned with my problem, but it's all going over my head at the moment.

So in conclusion, I'm looking for MLEs for $k$ and $a$, though I guess I would also need to address the cutoff for small $x$ somehow.

Comment: How committed are you to fitting a power law?  It won't work well and will be terrible for about half the particles.  What is the objective of fitting a distribution?

Comment: I guess rather quite commited? I know it sounds silly, but that's what people in my field did (don't ask me how; from what I've learned now I would guess they actually just fitted histograms like I did), and I would like to compare their results to mine to see if I find similar exponents.

Comment: The power law distribution as typically written has a negative exponent:  $kx^{-\alpha}$, and your eyeball estimate is at $\alpha = 3$ in that formulation, so the Clauset et al. paper would apply.

Comment: It is probably not to often that a sample from a power law distribution with $\alpha \approx 3$ will have the two leftmost bins with smaller frequencies than the third bin when the bin width is around 0.02 as in your example data.  The point is that it seems that a power law would not be a good fit for your data - unless maybe you're only interested in the righthand tail which (I think) is part of why @whuber is asking you about your objective.

Comment: @jbowman I see. But their formula

$$\hat{\alpha} = 1 + n\left[ \sum_i^n \text{ln}\frac{x_i}{x_\text{min}-1/2} \right]^{-1}$$

doesn't work for my data since $x_\text{min}-1/2$ would be negative. I don't understand why the formula is limited like that. Though I guess I could just scale up my $x$ with some constant, calculate $\hat{\alpha}$ and scale it back down?

Comment: @JimB Hi, yes, I am basically only interested in the righthand tail, but without the histogram I don't know where it starts, and where it starts in the histogram depends on the bin size. So I'm not sure how I can incorporate that information in my fit using MLEs. The leftmost bins have smaller frequencies due to a bias, because their $x$ are at the limit of what I can detect (which is also why there are no bins for even smaller $x$; however we know from other data that the power law holds true for a few more orders of magnitude smaller).

Comment: @JimB Could that be an argument for the choice of bin size? I.e. I should chose a bin size so that I don't see a drop off at the lefthand side?

Comment: One way to approach this problem is to fit a likely distribution that has this unimodal shape and exhibits a power tail to the right.  It's hard to nominate any distributions without understanding the origin of the data, though.  Many other approaches are possible, but they require more guidance to be successful: exactly how would you trade off errors in fitting the tail against bad fits at the left?  What has been done in your literature could provide guidance. In many cases what has been published is statistically poor, so following the literature blindly is never a good idea.

Comment: There are lots of details you'll need to consider such as:  (1) Do you have the raw data or just the binned data?  (2) How is your data obtained?  (3) is there censoring or truncation?  Also, when you say that "where it starts in the histogram depends on the bin size" I don't understand why you say that because the bin size is completely in your control and the smooth underlying probability density presumably exists with or without an artificial construct like a bin.  Maybe consulting with a university statistics department would be warranted.  Some offer free services.

Comment: @whuber thanks! I'm basically only interested in fitting the tail on the right. Fitting the drop off to the left is not relevant at all since it is caused by an observational bias against small particles. While in general it might be interesting to get a better idea about the severity of that bias, it's not relevant for the moment. Regarding the literature, as far as I can tell they fitted the histogram (somtimes in log-log space), but they are often not explicit about how they derived the the exponent of the power law.

Comment: @JimB thank you! (1) I do have the raw data. (2) I'm not exactly sure what you mean. The radii are derived from the flux of point sources. There certainly are errors in the radii, mostly stemming from a variance in the brightness values. (3) Do you mean if I have left out data? Or do you mean biases? The strongest bias by far is the one against small particles. The plot includes all data for which we could determine the radii.

Comment: @JimB "*because the bin size is completely in your control and the smooth underlying probability density presumably exists with or without an artificial construct like a bin*" that's exactly my point. So gauging the drop off on the left by means of the histogram is not a good idea, but the histogram at least tells me that there is one. So when I fit the histogram, I can easily take that into consideration and only fit the bins to the right (and which ones those are depends on the bin size, so not good). But when I use an MLE, I don't know how I can account for it. Stats. dep. is a good idea!

Comment: I would make an effort to model the "observational bias."  But a quick-and-dirty solution is to artificially left-truncate the data and use MLE to fit a Pareto distribution to the remainder.  Because that's dead simple and a quick calculation, you could (and should) also study how the solution varies with the choice of truncation threshold.  That would provide insight into how much that (somewhat) arbitrary choice affects your conclusions.

Comment: @whuber fair point. So what would that MLE look like which accounts for the truncation threshold? If you post an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: @whuber thanks again for your help. I think I finally understand now, see my answer below.

Comment: Same goes to you @JimB ! Unfortunately, I cannot tag both of you in the same comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after getting statistical consultation from my university and reading [Clauset et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062) and [White et al.](https://esajournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1890/07-1288.1) more carefully, I think I finally understand what is the right approach. So adapting Clauset et al.'s terminology, assume I am trying to fit a power law of the following form:

$$f(x) = x^{-\alpha}$$

### Previous Issues

The first issue I had was that I assumed that power laws would generally have positive exponents, but apparently this is not so; it seems like in literature, the term "power law" typically referrs to power laws with negative exponents. In the beginning however, this confused me, so because of the positive $\alpha$ values, I thought Clauset at al. did not apply to my case.

The second issue was that I misunderstood what Clauset at al.'s $x_\text{min}$ was used for, as I was still thinking of power laws with a positive exponent, so the lower limit didn't make much sense to me. Now I get that for negative exponents, $f(x)$ diverges for $x \rightarrow 0$, and in order to have a probability density function $p(x)$, we need a lower limit for $x$ such that $\int_{x_\text{min}}^\infty p(x) dx = 1$.

The third issue was that I thought in my original formulation of $f(x)=k \cdot x^{-a}$, I should be able to fit $k$ and $\alpha$ independently. But now I understand that $k$ is not an independent parameter, but the normalization constant which depends on $x_\text{min}$ and $a$. So that's why I was never able to determine the MLEs of both $k$ and $a$.

Finally, the last issue was that I misunderstood what Clauset et al. referred to as the *continuous* and *discrete* cases. I thought this was referring to whether the data I was trying to fit was continous or discrete--in which case it was discrete of course--, when it was actually referring to whether the underlying distribution the data were drawn from is continuous or discrete--in which case it is continuous.

### Solution

So following Clauset et al.'s definition,

$$p(x) = C \cdot x^{-\alpha},$$

where $C$ is the normalization constant. For the continuous case this means that

$$C = (\alpha - 1) \cdot x_\text{min}^{\alpha - 1}.$$

More importantly however, instead of using the approximation suggested for the discrete case (which I originally thought I had to use but which doesn't work for my data), for the continuous case, the MLE for $\alpha$ is easy to compute via:

$$\hat{\alpha} = 1 + n \left[\sum_{i=1}^n \text{ln} \frac{x_i}{x_\text{min}}\right]^{-1},$$

"where $x_i$, $i = 1, ..., n$, are the observed values of $x$ such that $x_i \ge x_\text{min}$".

With this, it is only a matter of estimating the correct $x_\text{min}$. Clauset et al. for example suggests to fit the data using each $x$ value as $x_\text{min}$, and choosing the one that produced the smallest [Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Luckily, there already exists a Python library that can do all this: [`powerlaw`](https://pypi.org/project/powerlaw/) ([accompanying paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0085777)). (The same and similar packages are also awailable for several other programming languages, see e.g. [here](https://aaronclauset.github.io/powerlaws/).)

All that being said however, I guess one should be careful if a power law is even the right model in the first place, or if instead for example an exponential or lognormal distribution is the better choice. Next to the papers, this is for example also discussed by Aaron Clauset [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49269095/5472354), and the `powerlaw` package offers likelihood tests to check this. Though in my case, I think a power law still makes the most sense when considering the underlying physicals laws that generate the particle distribution:

[image]

Lastly for those interested, there is also another more recent paper on the power law fitting by [Virkar and Clauset](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3524).